# Invariant subspace of differentiation operator

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-operators, invariant-subspace

Let $D \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ be the differentiation operator, and let $U$ be an invariant subspace of $D$. Suppose there exists a $p \in U$ with deg $p = k$.

a) Show that
$\mathcal{P}_k(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq U$.

b) Evidently $\{0\}$, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, and $\mathcal{P}_k(\mathbb{R})$ are invariant subspaces of $D$ if $k$ is a nonnegative integer. Show that there are no others.

For a) I was thinking of showing that all elements of $\mathcal{P}_k(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as a basis of $U$, but I'm not sure how to show this generally. For b) I was thinking of trying to do a proof by contradiction, but I'm not sure where to get started (also I don't know if this is the best approach).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*. As $U$ is invariant under $D$, $Dp = p'$ belongs to $U$ and $\deg p' = k-1$.

Comment: I appreciate the hint. Do you know how I might go about showing (b)?

Comment: The first thing that came to mind: suppose $U$ is an invariant subspace, and that $U \neq \{0\}$. Then the set $A = \{k \in \mathbb N : \exists p \in U ( k = \deg p)\}$ is non-empty, and then try to prove that $U = \mathcal P_M(\mathbb R)$, where $M = \max A$.

Comment: I'll try that out for (b). I'm using your hint for (a), and I was thinking that since deg$p' = k - 1$ and there is a $p$ with deg$k$, then any polynomial of degree $k$ exists in the span of $U$. Would that be a valid proof?

Comment: If $p \in U$ and $\deg p = k$, it is not necessarily true that any polynomial of degree $k$ is in $U$. In fact you can only guarantee that any scalar multiple of $p$ is in $U$, since it is a subspace. I think the following can help you: if $n$ is a positive integer and there are polynomials $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_n$ such that $\deg p_i = i$, then $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_n$ is a basis for $\mathcal P_n(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: For your response regarding (b) I understand why I should show that $U=\mathcal{P}_M(\mathbb{R})$ but I am stuck on how to actually do that.

Comment: Pick $p \in U$ such that $\deg p = M$. Then by induction show that $p^{(k)} \in U$ for every $k \in \{0,\dots,M\}$, and because $\deg p^{(k)} = M-k$, then $p^{(M)},p^{(M-1)},\dots,p$ is a basis for $\mathcal P_M(\mathbb R)$, meaning that $\mathcal P_M(\mathbb R) \subseteq U$. To prove the other inclusion, use the fact that there are no polynomials in $U$ of degree $M+1$.